# HTML nest forms issue when rendered in MVC partial views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have some EditorFor views that need to render a pop-up div containing a form along with the input control. Unfortunately, this can result in nested forms. I would like the EditorFor view to render javascript in these cases to ensure they are moved out of any form they may have been rendered inside by appending them to the end of the body. Inside one such editor, I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(body).append($('#MyPopupDivContainingAForm'));
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately, the form is magically disappearing...even with this code removed. After the initial page render I inspected the DOM and all nested form elements don't exist. Their contents exist, but the wrapping form tag does not. Thus, my intended solution fails miserably. The form tags indeed exist when I view the page source. They're just being removed from the DOM. I don't know exactly what is removing the form elements. I am using unobtrusive validation.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to achieve what I need? I would love to simply have @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyLookup) be able to render everything I need. As a workaround right now, I have the lookup Div/Form as a separate action that I also have to include outside the main form in addition to the EditorFor.

Comment: Since you can't nest forms, and since you don't even want to nest forms... why are you nesting forms and then trying to work around it?

Comment: I am not intentionally nesting forms. It's a by-product of an editor needing to render HTML that needs to exist elsewhere in the DOM. I can do this all day using the script above, but it doesn't work when a form tag exists.